# how to display a table retrieved from database to a jsp page via a controller page in Struts framework

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts

i have created a model class to connect with database with a function that retrives a table data.now this function should return whole resultset back to a Controller action page.
further controller action should send the data to jsp page for client viewing.

or simply how to hold Resultset data from query like..select * from table

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset/1832524#1832524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model class you can convert your ResultSet into List which subsequently returned to view.The only code you need to write is converting ResultSet into List of Object

Comment: i used ArrayList.i got class cast exception:ResultSet cannot be cast to ArrayList

Comment: Yeah ResultSet can't be converted into ArrayList. You need to iterate over ResultSet and insert each object from ResultSet into ArrayList