# oracle connection in jsp

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc, database-connection

I am new to both jsp as well as oracle.

I just want to know the steps for connecting an oracle 10g database with a jsp page.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps.

1. [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) do this in a JSP file. Do this in a Java class.
2. Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). You can download the Oracle JDBC driver [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html) and find Oracle-specific JDBC documentation [here](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/toc.htm) (code samples starts in chapter 3). Play around it in a simple Java class with a `main()` method in an IDE or CMD as long until you get the grasp. May take a day or two. It boils down to loading the JDBC driver, getting a DB connection and then executing the query on it.
3. Create a Javabean class which represents a single entity containing information of a single table row. Create a DAO (Data Access Object) class which offers methods to create, read, update and delete the entity/entities. Test it thoroughly using a simple Java class with a `main()`.
4. Create a Servlet class which has the `doGet()` and/or `doPost()` methods implemented according to the functional requirements and uses the DAO class to obtain or persist the entities of interest.

#### Related questions:

- [Displaying resultset in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset)
- [Places where Javabeans are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727603/places-where-java-beans-used/1729230#1729230)
- [DAO tutorial - Basic introduction to a JDBC DAO](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)