# Sending multiple values from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet code where I check for username and password in a helper class and after checking it comes back to servlet and lists users. The username along with the list of users must be displayed in the jsp. How to send both the values? Here is the code which I have tried. It displays nothing
String outp=t.Welcome(name, pwd);

```
String Users=t.List_Of_Users();
String User[]=Users.trim().split(" ");
request.setAttribute("name", User);
response.sendRedirect("Welcome_User.jsp?Users="+User+"&outp="+outp);
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you use forwarding (`request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome_user.jsp").forward()`) - just add another `request.setAttribute("attrName", value);`
- if you retain the redirect - add another get parameter. `Welcome_User.jsp?Users="+User+"&outp="+outp + "&another=" + another;` (and remove the `request.setAttribute(..)`)

In order to represent an array as string you have multiple options. One of which is `Arrays.toString(array)`

(Note that sending a password as a get parameter is a security problem.)

Comment: +1. But I believe the latter option would depend upon the implementation of `toString()` method, and might not work as expected.

Comment: In the snippet, its an array. I know, naming convention is bit screwed up. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set as many attributes as you want , also optimization should be taken care of. ,

```
request.setAttribute("key1", Object1);
request.setAttribute("key2", Object2);
request.setAttribute("key3", Object3);
.
.
.
request.setAttribute("keyn", Objectn);
```

then

```
String destination = "/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp";
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: These are not parameters, these are attributes. Both are having different meaning here, in this context. So, you should be careful. ;)

Comment: @Adeel yeah . I think OP wants to pass data from servlet to jsp, So i don't think any issue with this approach. I know attribute and parameter are different things, Thanks btw :)

Comment: @org.life.java: I edited your post, I hope you didn't mind. Now, I hope, you already got what I meant.

Comment: why is result.jsp in WEB-INF. isn't WEB-INF for the classes, lib, configuration folders and files?

Comment: @Adeel Thanks, I didn't re-check my answer after your comment ;) Thanks btw

Comment: @user521180: No, `WEB-INF` is there, so no resource can access the inside things from outside. Simple as that.

Comment: @user521180 Yeah, it was just to demonstrate

Comment: @org.life.java: No no buddy, they are not. That was perfectly fine. You can revert the thing if you want to.

Comment: @Adeel how will I access the jsp using GET request directly if its in `WEB-INF`

Comment: @org.life.java: The question is why on earth you want to access a JSP directly, without going through a servlet? Its this way `request-initiated -> servlet-mapping -> servlet -> jsp -> request-fulfilled`

Comment: @Adeel totally agree with you. but if OP wants directly to display JSP then ?, Its good thing to hide jsp directly from user that is true,

Comment: @org.life.java: Then we have to tell OP, that its not a good practice and so discouraged, in order to make our life easier. Do you really wanna see those kinda code from your fellow programmers? I doubt it. :)

Comment: @Adeel just FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430647/jsp-java-code-html-table/4430688#4430688   :)

Comment: @user521180 follow this discussion you will have great idea how it should be designed, Thanks @Adeel :)

Comment: @org.life.java: I have visited your referred thread, but I hardly can find any relation between this and that. :(

Comment: @Adeel there is some concern of this link and this discussion, anyways

Answer (score 3):

[`response.sendRedirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) will clear the buffer, which apparently means any request attributes previously set will not be retained.

In your case, I believe, its better to use [`RequestDispatcher.forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29), after setting your desired attributes in request object.

NB:By convention you must define your variable names starting with a small letter. For example, `String user;`, instead of `String User;`. Second, the method names should not use underscores. Further, I would suggest self-explanatory names. Below is your snippet with a little renaming.

```
String userNamesStr =t.userNamesSpaceDelimited();
String[] userNameArr = userNamesStr.trim().split(" "); // Or userNames, but we usually follow this for List
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values = getParameterValues(“Input Parameter”);
```

try this. Read more about this method